# jest describe suite fails but running test independently succeeds

Tags: typescript, jestjs

When I run each test alone then they both succeed. But when I run them together by `npm test` the second test fails:

```
Expected number of calls: 2
Received number of calls: 4
```

I have the following code: (short and cutted)

```
describe('checkDonations', () => {
test('it should call twice (test 1)', async () => {
    const axiosSpy = jest.spyOn(axios.default, 'get')
        .mockImplementation(() => {
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                resolve({
                    data: {
                        status: [
                            {
                                "created": "2020-04-08 21:20:17",
                                "timestamp": "1586373617",
                                "statusName": "new"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                })
            })
        });

    await checkDonations(null, {});

    expect(axiosSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
})

test('it should call twice (test 2)', async () => {
    const axiosSpy = jest.spyOn(axios.default, 'get')
        .mockImplementation(() => {
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                resolve({
                    data: {
                        status: [
                            {
                                "created": "2020-04-08 21:20:17",
                                "timestamp": "1586373617",
                                "statusName": "final_success"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                })
            })
        });

    await checkDonations(null, {});

    expect(axiosSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
})
})
```

The tests are cutted to display the issue. As you can see they are almost equal and each one has his own const of spy. Only the return value of the axiosSpy different. So I cannot place it in `before each`.

Why does the second test fail when I run them by `npm test` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should maybe reset your mocks in a beforeEach ? I use something like the following code :

```
beforeEach(() => jest.resetAllMocks())
```

Comment: Thx, this works! I am still confused. Is this the usual/normal behavior a test framework has?

Comment: @EroStefano Yes. Consider enabling resetMocks in Jest config, it's not a default for some reason.

Comment: I had the same issue and this solved my problem, thanks! However, I had specified beforeEach(() => jest.clearAllMocks()) ....should work the same, right? It's still a mistery

Comment: Not working, unfortunately. I'll try adding a timeout, as the other answer suggests.

Comment: I see this confusion often reset vs clear. reset will actually destroy your mock. Clear will remove any scoped data the mock has stored. Denefinitly use clear and not reset in before each, you will actually execute axios request

Answer (score 2):

Delete the build-generated folder(egs: dist) and try again. It works for me.

Answer (score -1):

If running tests individually results in everything passing, but running tests alongside a larger number of tests causes a failure, it's often fixed by giving the test a little more time to complete.

```
await waitFor(
  () => {
    let rows = getAllByTestId(distributionResultsTable, "table-row");
    expect(rows).toHaveLength(101);
  },
  { timeout: 2000 } // needs extra time
);
```

Comment: Adding timeouts is not a good solution. We should fix leaky data or wait on unresolved operations